# Definition of matrix norm induced by vector $p$-norm

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-analysis, normed-spaces, matrix-norms

I'm having a bit of trouble understanding the exact definition of a matrix norm that is induced by the vector norm. In this specific case, our matrix norm definition is:
$$||A|| = \max\limits_{x \neq 0}\frac{||Ax||}{||x||}$$
My textbook defines them for $p = 1, \infty$, but says that $2$ and others are difficult to compute. My question is what exactly does this definition mean? $||Ax||$ and $||x||$ are both scalars, so what does the $\max$ signify?. The textbook defines the functions as below:
$$||x||_p = (\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}|x_i|^p)^\frac{1}{p}$$ Suppose our matrix and vectors are below and $p$ = 1:
$$||A||_1 = \max\limits_{x \neq 0}\frac{||Ax||_1}{||x||_1}\\
||Ax||_1 =   \begin{bmatrix}
    a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} \\
    a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} \\
    a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33}
  \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
    a_{11}x_1 & a_{12}x_2 & a_{13}x_3 \\
    a_{21}x_1 & a_{22}x_2 & a_{23}x_3 \\
    a_{31}x_1 & a_{32}x_2 & a_{33}x_3
  \end{bmatrix}\\ = x_1(a_{11} + a_{21} + a_{31}) + x_2(a_{21} + a_{22} + a_{23}) + x_3(a_{31}+a_{32}+a_{33})\\[0.1in]
\text{and for x we have}\\
||x||_1 = x_1 + x_2 + x_3$$
So then the division of these are just scalars, but clearly I'm missing something from the definition (i.e. $\max$ means what?). Also is that the book has an equivalence of that $|A|_1$ is equal to the maximum column sum of the matrix $A$, but my calculation does not lead to that. Can someone enlighten me on what it is I'm missing from this?

Comment: It’s right there in the definition: the matrix norm is the maximum value of this ratio taken over *all* non-zero vectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To simplify the definition let us begin with a simple example :
$$
A=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 2 & 0 \\
0&0&5
\end{array}
\right)
$$
Let $X=(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3$ so $AX=(x,2y,5z)$, $\|X\|=|x|+|y|=|z|$ and $\|AX\|=|x|+|2y|+|5z|$ it's obvious that $f(x,y,z)=\|AX\|/\|X\|$ is a function of $X=(x,y,z)$
for example $f(1,1,0)=3$ and $f(0,0,1)=5$ etc

But we can see that :

> $$
> 0\leq f(x,y,z)\leq 5 \qquad \forall (x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^3 \textrm{ such that } |x|+|y|+|z|\ne 0
> $$

In fact :
the first inequality is trivial because the norm is non-negative, for the second
$$
5-f(x,y,z)=5-\frac{|x|+2|y|+5|z|}{|x|+|y|+|z|}=\frac{4|x|+3|y|}{|x|+|y|+|z|}\geq 0
$$
and the maximum of $\|AX\|/\|X\|$ is $5$ [ $X=(0,0,1)$ it's calculated up her] (and remark that $5$ is equal to the maximum column sum of the matrix $A$)

For general cases not as your calculation the function $f$ is :
$$
f(x,y,z)=\frac{  |a_{11}x + a_{12}y + a_{13}z|+|a_{21}x + a_{22}y + a_{23}z|+|a_{31}x + a_{32}y + a_{33}z|}{|x|+|y|+|z|}
$$
If we put $\alpha$ is the maximum column sum of the matrix $A$ for example $\alpha=|a_{13}|+|a_{23}|+|a_{33}|$ :

> $$
> 0\leq f(x,y,z)\leq \alpha \qquad \forall (x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^3 \textrm{ such that } |x|+|y|+|z|\ne 0
> $$

In fact :
the first inequality is trivial because the norm is non-negative, for the second
\begin{eqnarray}
\alpha-f(x,y,z)&=& \alpha-\frac{|a_{11}x + a_{12}y + a_{13}z|+|a_{21}x + a_{22}y + a_{23}z|+|a_{31}x + a_{32}y + a_{33}z|}{|x|+|y|+|z|}\\
&\geq & \alpha-\frac{|x|(|a_{11}|+|a_{21}| +|a_{31}| ) +|y|(|a_{12}| + |a_{22}|+|a_{32}|)+|z|( |a_{13}|+|a_{23}|+|a_{33}|)}{|x|+|y|+|z|} \\
&=&\frac{|x|(\alpha -(|a_{11}|+|a_{21}| +|a_{31}|) ) +|y|(\alpha-(|a_{12}| + |a_{22}|+|a_{32}|))}{|x|+|y|+|z|} \geq 0
\end{eqnarray}

and the maximum of $\|AX\|/\|X\|$ is $\alpha$ [ $X=(0,0,1)$ ] 
So 
$$
\|A\|_1=\sup_{\|X\|\ne 0} \frac{\|AX\|}{\|X\|}=\alpha
$$